# Why did shimx64.efi suddenly disappear?

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, uefi, windows-10

#### Summary:

Having installed Ubuntu with UEFI enabled, and secure boot disabled, I re-enabled secure boot and added `shimx64.efi` as trusted for executing. Then in my BIOS's boot menu, I chose `shimx64.efi`, and Ubuntu 16.04.1 booted. Wanting to see it boot without manually selecting `shimx64.efi`, I rebooted, and this time Windows 10 started up. So I went to the UEFI boot priority and moved `shimx64.efi` to the top and rebooted. Still it was Windows that booted. Rebooting, I opened the boot menu and specifically chose to boot `shimx64.efi`. And Windows booted.

#### Longer version:

On a new Acer Aspire E 15 I first set up Windows 10, then installed Ubuntu 16.04.1 from an SD. Not being very familiar with UEFI, I had secure boot still enabled. During the install it said it needed to disable secure boot if I wanted to install third-party drivers. It also prompted me to create a password it would prompt for after a reboot.* After the install, Ubuntu never started (and therefore never prompted for that password).
<sup>*From my understanding of its explanation, the password was to be used one-time, to prove upon the next boot that I was not an attacker. I believe it was a temporary replacement for secure boot, since Ubuntu would have to disable it.</sup>

I then installed a second time, overwriting the initial Ubuntu install. This time I had switched the boot system to legacy/BIOS, not realizing it needed to be UEFI because Windows was installed with UEFI.

Once I learned that, I installed a third time, again overwriting the previous Ubuntu install. Before the install I disabled secure boot, but afterwards I enabled it again so I could add `shimx64.efi` as trusted. Then I booted `shimx64.efi` through the BIOS's boot menu, and Ubuntu booted fine. Shutting it down, I decided to see if I could get it to boot to Ubuntu without manual intervention. Instead, Windows booted. Shutting it down again, I changed the UEFI boot order to have `shimx64.efi` at the top. Still the default boot went to Windows. So I went to the BIOS's boot menu, and manually selected `shimx64.efi` again. And *again* it booted Windows.

#### Important related problem

After my first Ubuntu install I had trouble selecting a UEFI file as trusted,  because after going to `HDD0 > <EFI> > <ubuntu>` *nothing* was shown in that pane, not even `<.>` and `<..>`, the current and parent directories. So I would press <kbd>ESC</kbd> and again select "Select an UEFI file as trusted for executing." The `<OEM>`, `<Microsoft>`, and `<Boot>` directories (siblings to the `<ubuntu>` directory) seemed to have normal contents.

However, now when I go there, I again see *nothing* in the `<ubuntu>` directory. This change happened at the same time that I had the surprise of booting into Windows when I expected Ubuntu (or perhaps when I successfully booted Ubuntu). Additionally, if I remember correctly, the top level had in addition to `HDD0` another option (something like `<boot>`, but that is now gone as well).

I haven't been able to find other reports of not being able to reach the `shimx64.efi` file from the BIOS, and certainly not its disappearance (the disappearance of the entire `<ubuntu>` directory's contents actually).

What I have been calling "the BIOS,"* probably more accurately called the "Setup Utility" is titled "InsydeH2O Setup Utility" at "Rev. 5.0". The "H2O" in the name could have a zero rather than the letter O, as it's not possible to differentiate in the font.
<sup>*I'm inferring (possibly incorrectly) that UEFI and BIOS are both simply boot managing systems, and that the setup utility traditionally used to configure the BIOS got called the BIOS.</sup>

Now the only option presented in the boot manager is Windows Boot Manager. The `shimx64.efi` option might have disappeared when I did "Erase all Secure boot Setting" or when I disabled secure boot. Keep in mind that this is not an exact log of what I did, as I did a lot of troubleshooting as I went.

#### Notes

Ideally I'd like to be able to choose between Ubuntu and Windows from GRUB.

I checked the SD for errors before the first and last installs, and none were found.

#### The questions

1. Why is `shimx64.efi` gone from the UEFI menu?
2. How can I get it back (or otherwise fix the boot)?

Comment: Just discovered that `shimx64.efi` is now in `HDD0 > <boot-sav>`. Unfortunately, booting it takes me to a GRUB command line. Presumably, the file being moved, GRUB cannot find Ubuntu. Still confused here.

Comment: I've gotten fed up with Windows and just wiped it and did a clean install of Ubuntu. After a few difficulties I've gotten it booting fine with UEFI and secure boot enabled. Tip to anyone who has similar problems (especially with "InsydeH2O Setup Utility"): Try exiting setup and saving changes after each change you make. Then enter it again and make the next change. It seems it doesn't always tell you if a change doesn't take effect immediately (including resetting settings). I'm still interested in the questions here though, because I may try to dual boot in the future, and because I'm curious

Answer (score 1):

I realize you've worked around your problems by deleting Windows from the computer; however, chances are the problem was caused by the Windows Fast Startup and/or Hibernation features. These features can leave partitions accessed by Windows (including the [EFI System Partition,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) where boot loaders reside) in an inconsistent state. You must disable these features in a dual-boot between Windows (versions 8 and later) and anything else (including Ubuntu). See [here](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html) and [here](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2859-hibernate-enable-disable-windows-10-a.html) for information on how to disable these features. Note that after disabling the features, you might need to do a `CHKDSK` from Windows or a `dosfsck` from Linux, and perhaps restore files that have been lost.

Also, some EFIs have problems with small or FAT16 ESPs. For this reason, I recommend making your ESP 550 MiB in size. This size is big enough that tools like `mkdosfs` will make it FAT32, rather than FAT16; and it's big enough to get past the problems that some EFIs have with small FAT filesystems.

Comment: Thanks. I thought of the fast startup issue after posting the above and disabled it, but didn't know anything about doning `CHKDSK` or `dosfsck`. This is quite likely the issue. After I posted this question I was unable to install Ubuntu alongside Windows. The GRUB bootloader would always fail to install (so I just wiped and installed Ubuntu). I'm guessing installing Windows alongside Ubuntu now would be difficult/a real pain, right? I might get an SSD sometime and reinstall then...

Comment: It is possible to install Windows after Ubuntu; however, you'll almost certainly have to either re-install GRUB or adjust your boot loader priorities after installing Windows. Also, in any dual-boot configuration on a modern computer, it's imperative that you understand your boot mode (BIOS/CSM/legacy vs. EFI/UEFI). See [this page of mine](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html) for details. Some details of how you'd go about installing Windows at this point vary with your Ubuntu boot mode.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was harder but just how hard I wasn't too sure.  Thanks for the article. I need to sit down with that some time and really try to understand how the whole booting system works (I have some idea but there are gaps in my knowledge). I'll accept the answer if/when I determine this was the cause of the problem.